# Angular CLI with Yarn 2 (dlx)

Tags: angular, angular-cli, yarnpkg

I am trying to start new Angular project using `ng new my-app` together with yarn 2 dlx command. I.e. get latest Angular CLI and create new project. I tried following but it failed:

```
λ yarn dlx --package @angular/cli ng new my-app
yarn run v1.22.4
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "C:\\Users\\sax\\Documents\\devel"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

When I use `npx` it works:

```
npx --package @angular/cli ng new my-app
```

I don't understand why for `dlx` yarn asks for package.json. Do I need to enable berry somewhere? Is there any way to create new project Angular with yarn 2 straight away?

Comment: Can you share your yarn version, you might be using yarn 1, dlx command is available in yarn 2. Besides Angular does not support Yarn 2 yet, you can check the status here (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16980)

Comment: @iesen - version is visible in the first command - v1.22.4. Note yarn does not complain about `dlx` but about missing package.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out that `berry` needs to be set first in the target directory:

```
$ mkdir my-app && cd my-app
$ yarn set version berry
$ yarn dlx --package @angular/cli@next ng new my-app --directory=. --packageManager=yarn
```

But as @iesen wrote already - Angular does not support Yarn 2 so I guess it is not worth the trouble. I had to use `@angular/cli@next` just to create project and install dependencies - Angular 9 uses typescript 3.6 which cannot be installed by yarn 2. And then came the issues from [github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16980](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16980).